# Backup files from liveCD

Tags: boot, backup, live-cd

My Ubuntu doesn't boot. I was able to boot from liveCD and connect an external hard drive. I want to  backup my files.  I tried `cp -r /home destination`, but I get problem with spaces in filenames, symlinks, errors "Cannon create fifo: Operation not permitted" "Permission denied" "Invalid argument" and plenty more. What is the best way to do it? Will `cp -a` fix these issues or should I do something more clever?

EDIT:
Also in live mode I didn't have permission to view one folder in my home directory. I run `sudo nautilus` to view it.

EDIT2:

So far I found out that using `rsync` doesn't have problems with filenames. But it doesn't copy .so and .a files. Also it is running extremely slow comparing to cp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it is not the command, which is a problem. The commands posted by user34716 are correct. One has to use `cp -ar` to preserve attributes and symlinks.

However, the problem is that these attributes cannot be represented in all file systems. So if disk is not ext4 formatted, it is better to create archive. For liveCD  the command will be:

```
tar -c -z -f /my/backup/disk/home.tar.gz -C / media/ubuntu/deviceName/home
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this command a try:

```
cp -ar /source/dir/. /destination/dir/
```

The -a option is an improved recursive option, it preserves all file attributes, and also preserve symlinks.

the r in -ar is an option to copy files/directories recursively, it is required for copying folders within the folder where your files are located.

The . at end of the source path is cp syntax that allows you to copy all files and folders, included hidden ones.

Since the -a option preserves file attributes, you will need to use sudo to view them or or run this command. (change user and group names)

```
sudo chown -r user:group /directory/of/file/backups
```

The above command will make you the owner of the backed up files.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I was told, the problem is that external hard has a different file system, this is why not all properties and things can be represented.

Comment: @Noidea as far as I know, if Ubuntu live can see and access the data on the drive, it should be able to be copied with all of the permissions and properties intact. On another note, if you do use the cp command, use it with sudo in front.